# How can I make a for loop that loops all elements with a specific class and print all the text found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mJmf.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions
import time
import pyautogui as pg


path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.maximize_window()


driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")


Email_entry= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')

Email_entry.send_keys("MyEmail")


Pass_entry= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')


Pass_entry.send_keys("MyPassword")


sign_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button')

sign_in.click()


time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/CSGOTradingCommunity/pending_posts")

time.sleep(5)

See_all_posts = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

See_all_posts.click()


See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(1)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(2)
See_all_posts.send_keys(Keys.HOME)
```

I'm trying to create a code that accepts posts in my group that have a specific string in the post description but nearly all Facebook elements are dynamic I was able to find the class each individual post container which is 'tr9rh885' but every thing else is shared so I couldn't make it loop through all post the code would stop when it found the first post with this class.
Any ideas how to work around this ?

P.s: This is my first time writing a script any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('some_class')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Also, if you search "selenium, find element by class" in search bar, you will find at least 100 such examples.